# Word or phrase to describe a person's taste in media and entertainment?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am looking for a word that encompasses a person's taste in a wide variety of media and entertainment, including but not limited to movies, shows, music, musicians, actors, and anime.

Sample Sentence:

> Show the world your [requiredWord].

The best I've come up with is "taste in media" and "media preference".

> Show the world your taste in media.

Is there any other word or short phrase to describe a person's taste in media?

Comment: *Share your flair.* (Where *flair* means *style*.)

Comment: There is no such word.  probably, the only way to get one is to become a social media figure with a sufficient following so that so that any word you coin with catch on.  If manage that, then the word does not matter all that much:  'show me your medprefs' sounds pretty ghastly to me, but that would not prevent a socmed star's jargon from catching on.